# Objective-C search nsstring for UiTextView content

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a `NSString` which contains multiple (thousand) names (forenames and surnames), and I would like the opportunity to input a name (forename or surname or both) in to a `UITextView`, and then check if the name is on the list.

Let's find a surname!

```
for (NamesString *items in _feedArray){
    if ([nameText.text isEqualToString: items.surname]){
       NSLog(@"BINGO");
    }else{
       NSLog(@"NOPE");
     }
}
```

I always get `NSLog(@"NOPE")`.

Comment: What ur feedArray contains and what is ur input?

Comment: You should really check the documentation. NSArray has a `containsObject:` method.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a single `NSLog(@"BINGO")` hidden among thousands of `NSLog(@"NOPE")`? Also, could you post an example of `nameText.text` and `items.surname`? It could be that you have a stray space or comma that's causing `isEqualToString:` to return `false`.

Comment: The array contains forenames and surnames.